# Power Query error in connecting to data source using an encrypted connection

Tags: powerquery

I am trying to connect to a db running on (localdb)\v11.0 using power query, but I always got the following error:

> DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to does not support encryption.
> Details: 
> Message=The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to does not support encryption.
> Number=20
> Class=20

Comment: Please enable tracing in Power Query and then reproduce the error. Once done, use the "send a frown" feature to report the problem and attach your traces. Tracing can be enabled from the Options dialog on the Power Query ribbon.

Answer (score 4):

In the Query Editor go to File->Options and Settings -> Data Source Settings.  Choose your (localdb)\v11.0 and select Edit and turn off "Encrypt Connections".  Once it is off you should be able to Refresh from the Home tab.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Power Query, manually turning off encryption would be the only way to resolve this.

If you get this message in newer versions (2.27 or later), if you get this error you'll be directly prompted to turn off encryption. If that doesn't seem to be working, Send-A-Frown to get in touch with our support teams.